# how do you write custom shortcodes for product categories in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to take the woocommerce shortcode for outputting products from a category but add more data from custom fields created by advanced custom fields. Here is the code I'm working with

```
function category_products( $atts ) {

// global $woocommerce_loop;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'category'      => '',
    'per_page'  => '4',
    'columns'   => '4',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
), $atts));

$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array( esc_attr($category) ),
    'operator' => 'IN',
);
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => '_visibility',
    'value' => array('catalog', 'visible'),
    'operator' => 'IN',
);
$args = array(
    'post_type'   =>  'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    // 'stock'       =>  1,
    // 'showposts'   =>  3,
    // 'orderby'     =>  'rand',
    // 'order'       =>  'DESC',
    'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query,
    'tax_query'   => $tax_query
);


$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$html_out = '';

// $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) :

    $html_out .= '<ul>';

    while ($products->have_posts()) :   
        $products->the_post();  
        $product = get_product( $products->post->ID );

        $course_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $course_level = get_field( "course_level" );
        $course_id = get_field( "course_id" );
        $course_icon = get_field( "course_icon" );
        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post->ID);
        $url = get_permalink();

        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($products->post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all"));
        $first_term = $term_list[0];
        $first_term_slug = $first_term->slug;

        $explodedSlug = explode('-', $first_term_slug);

        // Output product information here

        $html_out .= '<li class="' . $first_term_slug . 'product type-product status-publish no-post-thumbnail first instock featured taxable shipping-taxable product-type-simple"><div class="entry-product">';
        $html_out .= '<div class="course-level">' . $explodedSlug[1] . '</div>';
        if( $course_icon ):
            $html_out .= '<div class="course-icon"><img src="' . $course_icon . '" alt="' . $course_title . '"></div>';
        endif;
        $html_out .= '<h4><a href="' . $url . '">' . $course_title . '</a></h4><p>' . $course_level . " - " . $course_id . '</p><p>' . $excerpt . '</p>';
        $html_out .= '</div></li>';

    endwhile;

    $html_out .= '</ul>';

else : // No results
    $html_out = "No Courses Found.";
endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();

return $html_out;
```

}

add_shortcode( 'category_products', 'category_products' );

I tried using a shortcode `[category_products category="grade-11"]` but it just outputting the `else`.